# How can I delete a downloaded file using Selenium RemoteWebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, remotewebdriver

I am writing a test to check that a file can be downloaded from a particular web page and I want it to be able to run both locally and remotely (i.e. on a node via Selenium grid). Before anyone links me to the 'do you really need to download the file?' article, I have already managed to download and check the file, I just need a way of deleting it after the test has completed. Just calling `File.delete();` or similar will only work locally (as far as I'm aware) so I can't use that to delete the file from the node machine. I'm aware of the class `org.openqa.selenium.io.TemporaryFileSystem` however I can't find any instructions for how to use it.

Can anyone offer a better solution than 'just run a script on the node machine to delete the file'? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can make the download folder shared. \youruser\downloads after that you can pass this path to the File.Delete(); and it will delete the desired files.

Answer (score 1):

Cleanup of downloaded files within session of Grid Node feature is planned:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/11457
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/11657

Answer (score -1):

This Worked for me

```
try 
{
if ((new File("Path")).delete()) {
                System.out.println("Pass");     
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed");
            }

          } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
          }
```

Comment: While this may be a great answer, I would recommend providing more information on how and why this is a workable solution so that others can more easily understand and use this answer.

Comment: As stated in the question, using `File.delete()` will *not* work when running on a remote node, as the file will be downloaded on the browser-hosting machine but the delete command will be run on the test-running machine.

Answer (score -1):

```
   ----------simply use this code for delete file in any folder-------------------       
   File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Updoer\\Downloads\\Inspections.pdf"); 
   if(file.delete())
   System.out.println("file deleted");
```

Comment: As stated in the question, using `File.delete()` will *not* work when running on a remote node, as the file will be downloaded on the browser-hosting machine but the delete command will be run on the test-running machine.

Answer (score -1):

The Below Code will sequentially delete all the files from folder

```
    File path = new File("Path of Folder");
    File[] files = path.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        System.out.println("Deleted filename :"+ file.getName());
        file.delete();
    }
```

Comment: As stated in the question and my responses to other answers, using `File.delete()` will not work when running on a remote node, as the file will be downloaded on the browser-hosting machine but the delete command will be run on the test-running machine.