# How can I delete file using Selenium RemoteWebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, remotewebdriver

using File.delete() will not work when running on a remote node, as the file will be downloaded on the browser-hosting machine but the delete command will be run on the test-running machine.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.  This is a good read for new users: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
It looks like you're trying to delete a file off the remote node that has been downloaded?  Per this issue https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5886, it's not something they support.  The only way this could work is if your running system has file access to the remote node, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30397049/229743

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.